# ¿Cuál es el problema de esta validación de campo existente en la BD?

Tags: php, mvc, formularios, validación

Tengo este registro en php y he puesto una condición para que si el usuario quiere registrarse con un email que ya está dado de alta en la BD, no le deje y le muestre un mensaje. Tengo un modelo vista controlador y he realizado la comprobación con el mysqli_num_rows, pero algo no he hecho bien y no me sale. Me aparece este error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'compruebaemail' (T_STRING), expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebBurger\public\forms\registro.php on line 25. De todas formas, creo que no he puesto bien los parámetros o algo así. Si me podéis echar una mano. Muchas gracias.

Fichero de formulario registro

```html
<form action="../public/forms/registro.php" method="post">
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="nombre">NOMBRE</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" maxlength="30" size="29" required /></dd>
                <dt><label for="apellidos">APELLIDOS</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" maxlength="30" required /></dd>
                <dt><label for="fecha_nacimiento">FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="date" id="fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento" required /></dd>
                <dt><label for="telefono">TELÉFONO</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="tel" id="telefono" name="telefono" required placeholder="XXXXXXXXX" pattern="[0-9]{9}" /></dd>
                <dt><label for="ciudad">CIUDAD</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" maxlength="50" required /></dd>
                <dt><label for="email">EMAIL</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="usuario@direccion.com" required maxlength="30" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" /></dd>
                <p class="texto-contra">
                    La contraseña debe contener al menos un número, una mayúscula, una minúscula y un mínimo de 8 caracteres.
                </p>
                <dt><label for="contrasena">CONTRASEÑA</label></dt>
                <button id="mostrar_contrasenaregistro" type="button" onclick="mostrarContrasenaregistro()"> <span class="fa fa-eye-slash icon"></span> </button>
                <dd><input type="password" id="contrasena" name="contrasena" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" maxlength="40" required /></dd>
                <dd><input type="submit" name="usub" value="¡Quiero registrarme!" /></dd>
            </dl>

        </form>
```

Este es el fichero php que recibe los datos y realizo la comprobación

```html
<?php

require_once(__DIR__.'/../../lib/controller/UsuarioController.php');

$un = $_POST['nombre'];
$ua = $_POST['apellidos'];
$uf = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
$ue = $_POST['email'];
$uc = $_POST['contrasena'];
$ut = $_POST['telefono'];
$uci = $_POST['ciudad'];

if(function compruebaemail($ue)==true){
    echo "<div style='color:red'>Esta dirección de email ya está dada de alta </div>";
}else {
    $cnt = new UsuarioController();
    $ins = $cnt->crearUsuario($un, $ua, $uf, $ue, $uc, $ut, $uci);
}



function compruebaemail($ue){
    $sql="SELECT * from usuarios WHERE email='$ue'";
    $result=mysqli_query($sql);
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
    
}

?><html>

<head>
    <title>Registro completado</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include(__DIR__.'/../../lib/inc/header.php'); ?>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Su registro se ha completado correctamente.<br> Se ha enviado un correo de confirmación a su cuenta.</h1>
        <a href="../index.php">Volver a la página principal</a>
    </div>
    <?php include(__DIR__.'/../../lib/inc/footer.php'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema lo tienes en la sintaxis del if:

```
if(function compruebaemail($ue)==true){
```

realmente ya tienes definida la funcion debajo, asi que solo tienes que llamarla con:

```
if(compruebaemail($ue)==true){
```

Comment: Y además, no es necesario comprobar que sea == true, ya que tu funcion retorna un booleano. 
O sea, 
if (compruebaemail($ue)) {...} sería suficiente.

Comment: perfecto! gracias!